# How can I perform element-wise subtraction in a RDD in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD like this:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1,0,1,1,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0,1])
```

I'm required to have an output like this

```
[1,0,0,1,1,1]
```

So subtraction element-wise and then absolute value. I am still a beginner in pyspark.
Any help would be appreciated.Since, I need to keep my computation down, converting to a dataframe wouldn't be advisable.

Comment: Please explain your use case. I think the structure of your input **`rdd1`** is incorrect. Also, please add whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In pure python, it would be :

```py
a, b = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

[x - y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
Out[2]: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1]
```

If you want to achieve the same in pyspark, it depends if you use columns, line or arrays ... Here, is one solution with data in columns :

```py
# based on above a and b
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(a, b), ["a", "b"])

df.show()
+---+---+                                                                       
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|
|  0|  1|
+---+---+

df.withColumn("c", F.col("a") - F.col("b")).show()
+---+---+---+                                                                   
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  1|
|  0|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|
|  0|  1| -1|
+---+---+---+
```